# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully when building on Docker now

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

It built fine before.

I did no change for when it still worked before.

Here are its final moments before dying.

As you can see, it dies on installing measurement.

Here is Docker code partial:

```
# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
WORKDIR /app
#RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is the error

```
#0 24.46 Collecting measurement==3.2.0
#0 24.48   Downloading measurement-3.2.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
#0 24.49   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 30.54   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 30.55   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 30.55   
#0 30.55   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#0 30.55   │ exit code: 1
#0 30.55   ╰─> [14 lines of output]
#0 30.55       Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 30.55         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
#0 30.55         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
#0 30.55         File "/tmp/pip-install-uis_8hdi/measurement_709a216af0574a738b280207cf3f2a2e/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
#0 30.55           setup(use_scm_version=True)
#0 30.55         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
#0 30.55           _install_setup_requires(attrs)
#0 30.55         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
#0 30.55           dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
#0 30.55         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 785, in fetch_build_eggs
#0 30.55           resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
#0 30.55         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
#0 30.55           raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
#0 30.55       pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (sphinxcontrib.applehelp 1.0.3 (/tmp/pip-install-uis_8hdi/measurement_709a216af0574a738b280207cf3f2a2e/.eggs/sphinxcontrib.applehelp-1.0.3-py3.8.egg), Requirement.parse('sphinxcontrib-applehelp'), {'sphinx'})
#0 30.55       [end of output]
#0 30.55   
#0 30.55   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 30.56 error: metadata-generation-failed
#0 30.56 
#0 30.56 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#0 30.56 ╰─> See above for output.
#0 30.56 
#0 30.56 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#0 30.56 hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install some libraries before you can install mysqlclient. Run this code:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

Hope it helps!